# Can't save Linq to XML elements addition

Tags: xml, linq, save, xmldocument

Having an issue opening, changing, and then saving changes to an XML file using Linq to XML.

Here's my code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xml/Campaigns.xml");

        XElement newCampaign = new XElement("campaign",
               new XAttribute("id", "2"),
               new XElement("name", "new campaign")
               );
        doc.Add(newCampaign);
        doc.Save("xml/Campaigns.xml");
```

I'm not getting any compile errors for opening, creating and adding the XElement, only when I try to save the changes.

The compile errors I'm seeing are: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Save(System.Xml.XmlWriter)' has some invalid arguments

and:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Xml.XmlWriter'

I'm not sure why it's making or expecting me use a XmlWriter because according to this I can save a string in the Save Method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830.aspx

If anyone could help, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you're using Silverlight (e.g. on Windows Phone 7) - where the [`Save` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338419%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) has fewer overloads. It's not clear where you're trying to save the document to, but if you *are* using Silverlight then you'll need to use one of the overloads listed in the linked page.

Comment: I am doing this on Windows Phone. It's a Silverlight with XNA application, so I figured with the XNA logo in the msft link I provided it'd work, but you bring up an excellent point.

Guess I'll start brushing up on the XmlWriter.

Comment: @MarkMclaughlin: You don't need to do that - but you'll need to open an `IsolatedStorageFileStream`, and then call save with *that* as the argument.

Comment: Jon thanks again for pointing me in the right direction. When investigating isolated storage I realized there's capabilities for a database now in Windows Phone, and I've worked out a solution leveraging that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202876(v=vs.92).aspx